# Conectar con impresora Xprinter XP-365B

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un simple script de python e intento hacer que imprima una simple línea en una etiqueta de la impresora. Estoy usando la librería `escpos` para python.

Usé IA dándole el hardwareID de la impresora y me escribió el script. El puerto USB utilizado es: `USB001` He verificado que funcione correctamente, los drivers están instalados y la impresora es detectada por el sistema.

Dejo abajo el código y las fotos con el ID y el puerto, si alguien puede ayudarme (sé muy poco del tema, lo he ido sacando todo de tutoriales) muchas gracias.

```
import usb.core
import escpos.printer
# find the printer
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1FC9, idProduct=0x2016)
if dev is None:
        raise ValueError('Printer not found')

# create the printer object
p = escpos.printer.Usb(dev)

# print the string
p.text('Hello world\n')
```

La terminal me arroja:

EDIT: Cambié el código, busqué en internet y al parecer el idVendor y el idProduct eran incorrectos. Los corregí acorde a las indicaciones, pero la terminal me sigue arrojando:
*raise ValueError('Printer not found')
ValueError: Printer not found*

Esta vez saqué los datos del controlador de dispositivos: Dispositivo principal: USB\VID_1FC9&PID_2016\0123456789AB

Comment: Revisa siempre la documentación del software que estás usando. ¿Hiciste lo que indica [la página del módulo](https://pypi.org/project/escposprinter/), es decir, instalar pyusb y pillow? Revisaste como dicen ahí, el VendorID y ProductID (ahí en la ventana de propiedades de la impresora, esa lista desplegable te deja ver esos datos)?

Comment: hola @Alfabravo, Si, tengo pyusb y pillow instalado sin embargo, no estoy usando la librería escposprinter la que uso se llama escpos.printer cómo se muestra en el código. Ahora, en la ventana de propiedades de la impresora, me aparece solo el id de hardware, ni vendor ni product. Pero ví en varios tutoriales que esa es la información. El problema es que no se cómo ponerla en el Usb() Porque copiandolo textual no funciona.